# Encoding to VBR adds "-b 32" flag automatically

Tags: mp3, encoding, lame

Using LAME 3.99. I'm encoding files using `lame.exe -m j -V 0 -q 0 <file>`. When I open the encoded file in MediaInfo, the **Encoding settings** field shows `-m j -V 0 -q 0 -lowpass 22.1 --vbr-new -b 32`. The `-b 32` seems to be the default setting. Should I explictily pass in the `-b` flag with something higher like `-b 96` to limit the minimum bitrate to 96kbps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

With `-q 0` and `-V 0` you've told lame to be as true to the original as possible (subject to any `-B <max_kbps>` upper limit).

Very low bitrates (like the implicit `-b 32`) will *only* be used for ~silence, so a hard lower limit of `-b 96` would be wasteful only where it doesn't matter.

If you find a track with a lot of silence (like spoken word), watch the ASCII histograms during encoding, you'll see more low-bitrate frames, than you would for typical music.

Ages ago I experimented with `-V #` across lots of different music to see what the resulting min/max bitrates would look like.  You can poke around in the data & results here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15dulFA-wP7wZzIK7qCu0qCKHprYdbbFZ1ovBg8NKGKM/edit?usp=sharing#gid=4